# Symfony with easyadmin - homepage getting redirected to admin page

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I am using Symfony 5.0.4 with easyadmin by following this tutorial. 
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html

After installing easyadmin, I tried to get my homepage https://127.0.0.1:8000/. 
But it redirects to /admin. 
All config files are set by default.

How can I load the homepage without being redirected?

Comment: By default easyadmin use the path /admin, you can change this option on  easy_admin.yaml, https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/basic-configuration.html#changing-the-url-used-to-access-the-backend

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `config\packages\easy_admin.yaml` file and add a link to homepage into the menu:

```yaml
easy_admin:
    design:
        menu:
            - { route: 'homepage', label: 'Back to the website', icon: 'home'}
```

Do not forget to replace 'homepage' by the route name of your route page.
You can find the route to your homepage by type:

```
symfony console debug:route
```

PS: If the debug:route command is unknown, you should install debug-pack:

```
symfony composer req debug --dev
```

Then you have to search in your code the controller corresponding to the homepage route.
Here is an example:

```php
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage") <== This is the method called when I wand to display the homepage
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return new Response('This is an example');
    }
}
```

You should find the method called in your application and verify its code to find why it redirects you to the easyadmin route.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, Alexandre!

The problem was on the global route. I don't know why.

Example:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/", name="labs_")
 */

class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    // ...
}
```

When I moved route inside everything homepage started working.